# Error in Predict(a, group : predictors(s) not in model: group

Tags: predictive-models

I fit a model
a<- gls(Y ~  time + group , data=d,  correlation=corSpher(form = ~time | ID))

all look good (see the bottom output). When I tried to predict,
Predict(a, time, group)
Predict(a, time)
Predict(a, group)

it gave me this error:
Error in Predict(a, time, group) : predictors(s) not in model: time, group

I just can't figure out how to fix it. Please help.
Thanks.

######################################################

summary(a)
Generalized least squares fit by REML
Model: Y~ time + group
Data: d
AIC      BIC    logLik
4890.062 4913.663 -2440.031

Correlation Structure: Spherical spatial correlation
Formula: ~time | ID
Parameter estimate(s):
range
132.2148

Coefficients:
Value Std.Error  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 9.672495  3.137996 3.082380  0.0021
time        0.036201  0.023718 1.526312  0.1273
groupWKY    9.245532  3.343175 2.765494  0.0058

Correlation:
(Intr) time
time     -0.624
groupWKY -0.574  0.000

Comment: What you wrote is unreadable and unclear. Notice that there are text formatting utilities on our page, it also supports Markdown. Moreover, you posted code without context, so it would be hard if not impossible to answer, please add more details on what is happening in the code, what are you trying to do, etc.